# Generic order for pagination using OFFSET and FETCH

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to generate a generic order.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
    (col1 varchar(3)));

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @SkipRows int
    DECLARE @FetchRows int 
    DECLARE @Idlist varchar(100)

        SET @Idlist = '10,14,16,20,23,28,21,36,24,36,35,39,32,31,33'


        SET @sql = N'SELECT  a.col1 AS FROM tbl a (nolock) WHERE a.col1 IN(' + @Idlist +') ORDER BY (SELECT 0) '
                    + 'OFFSET  ' + @SkipRows  + '  ROWS  FETCH NEXT ' + @FetchRows  + ' ROWS ONLY '

INSERT INTO #TempTable ([col1])
    EXEC(@sql)
```

In the above query

** If I set 
    @SkipRows = 2 and @FetchRows = 4 Then I want to see the results as below :

```
  OrderNum   col1
     3          16
     4          20
     5          23
     6          28
```

**
     If I set   @SkipRows = 6 and @FetchRows = 2 Then I want to see the results as below :

```
OrderNum   col1
 7          21
 8          36
```

Note : OrderNum is not a column in my table.

Comment: So what seems to be the problem? Apart from the int to varchar conversion error when you concatenate the string

Comment: i want to get the order of col1 values.

Comment: If you order by col1 (which I assume holds the same values as the idlist variable, wouldn't the second example return 24 and 28? It does when I test it.

Comment: I am sorry I don't want to do any sort of order by.  I changed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a column alias for a.col1 and either have to cast the SkipRows and FetchRows variables to varchar for the concatenation, or use CONCAT like this:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT(N'
    SELECT 
       OrderNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)), 
       a.col1 AS col1 
    FROM tbl a (nolock) 
       WHERE a.col1 IN (',@Idlist, N') 
    ORDER BY (SELECT 0) OFFSET ', @SkipRows, N' ROWS FETCH NEXT ',
    @FetchRows, N' ROWS ONLY '
    )
```

This seems to work when I tried it (in that I get the expected results):

for `@SkipRows = 2 and @FetchRows = 4` this gets:

```
OrderNum             col1
-------------------- -----------
3                    16
4                    20
5                    23
6                    28
```

and for `@SkipRows = 6 and @FetchRows = 2` this gets:

```
OrderNum             col1
-------------------- -----------
7                    21
8                    36
```

Comment: but my requirment is i need the ordernum as shown in the question.

Comment: @BumbleBee Oh ok, I didn't get that, hang on a sec.

Comment: @Rajesh Yeah, it can be really useful, and performs quite well I believe.